# getting list without k'th element efficiently and non-destructively

Tags: python, list, copying

I have a list in python and I'd like to iterate through it, and selectively construct a list that contains all the elements except the current k'th element. one way I can do it is this:

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
for num, elt in enumerate(l):
  # construct list without current element
  l_without_num = copy.deepcopy(l)
  l_without_num.remove(elt)
```

but this seems inefficient and inelegant. is there an easy way to do it? note I want to get essentially a slice of the original list that excludes the current element.  seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

thank you for your help.

Comment: another way I thought of doing this is as follows:

# assume k is the element to be excluded
filter(lambda x: x[0] != k, l)

is this respectable? are there better ways?

Comment: Can you explain me what the expected result is? "NameError: name 'copy' is not defined"

Comment: It's not clear to me what the result of this operation is supposed to be.  The implementation you posted constructs but doesn't use 3 different copies of the original list, missing three different elements.  Can you clarify your goals?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
k = 1
l_without_num = l[:k] + l[(k + 1):]
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: +1, definitely heads and shoulders the best way!  Why iterate when you can slice and concatenate?-)

Comment: Does this work for all k < len(l)? What about negative indices?

Answer (score 9):

It would help if you explained more how you wanted to use it. But you can do the same with list comprehension.

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
k = 1
l_without_num = [elt for num, elt in enumerate(l) if not num == k]
```

This is also more memory efficient to iterate over if you don't have to store it in l_without_num.

Answer (score 2):

```
l=[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
k=1
l_without_num=l[:]   # or list(l) if you prefer
l_without_num.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i != k]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
`python -c "'\n'.join(mylist[:])" 2>NULL | sed '/mybadelement/d'`
```

lol

Answer (score 1):

Using difference operator on sets:

```
list(set(l).difference([l[k]])

l=[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
list(set(l).difference([l[1]]))
[('a', 1), ('c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, but the functional programmer in me would probably write this.

```
import operator
from itertools import *
def inits(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        yield list[:i]
def tails(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        yield list[i+1:]
def withouts(list):
    return imap(operator.add, inits(list), tails(list))

for elt, without in izip(l, withouts(l)):
    ...
```

---

```
import functools, operator
for elt in l:
    without = filter(functools.partial(operator.ne, elt), l)
```

I don't think it's the *right* thing to do, but it's short.  :-)

Comment: Maybe there should be an ifilter in there? :)

Comment: Would downvoters please comment why?  The first solution is equivalent to the leading answer, in results and algorithmic complexity.